# Please let me know how much time i have left to post another question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

so i just posted a question on the main site, and tried to ask another. i dunno why, but the system told me that i can only ask a question every forty minutes. so fine i'll wait in the chat room.

i tried clicking the post button again just now, and its still telling me You can only post once every 40 minutes but i asked the qeustion 20 minutes ago.

i think it should tell me how much time i have left so i know when i can come back and post again. i can do subtraction but telling me how much time i have left would be nice.

(also if someone could explain why i can't ask two questions back to back that would be nice. do i have too little points on the site? also why i have to wait 40 minutes to post on meta also?? it might just be easier not to try.)

Comment: regarding why this limit exists and its exact parameters, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/166155

Comment: oh its cuz i don't have 125 points? :( @double aa

Comment: @Samuel unfortunately, yes it's rep-based.  Across the network there have been a lot of users who post a bunch of low-quality questions very quickly (sometimes even spam), and SE opted for slowing people down instead of having a lot of questions to clean up after.  I'm sorry that this affects people asking constructive questions.  But you're more than halfway to being free of this limitation, so please hang in there!

Comment: @monica cellio Yeah. Maybe this means I should visit and ask questions more often instead of saving up questions and asking them all at once...

Comment: I encourage you to ask your questions when you think of them instead of saving them up.  Besides, sometimes you learn things from one question that you can apply to the next.

Comment: that makes sense, @monica cellio. will do!